# Is there a way to tell if a memory buffer was allocated and must be deleted?

Tags: c++

I came up with a clever (or stupid) design pattern.  In one of our use cases, there *might* be the need to create one *large* memory buffer that would be used over and over for the lifetime of the class instance.  In the case that we don't need the memory buffer, I'd like to avoid creating it.  So I came up with the following:

```
class Class {
  public:
    void func()
    {
      if (A) {
        // do something
      } else if (B) {
        // need data buffer, which we will recycle
        static float * data = new float[1000000];
        // do something with the data
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }

  ~Class() {
    // to delete[] or not to delete[] that is the question
  }
}
```

Is there a way to deallocate this buffer in the destructor?  I can use `delete[]`, but the question is: how do we know if we have to delete the buffer?  In other words, is there a clever way to know if `if (B)` was executed?  Of course I can do this with flags, but I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it.  The concept of a static memory buffer on the heap that may or may not be initialized is sort of confusing to me.

Comment: Any reason to not just use a member pointer?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't experienced enough of a developer to think of that obvious solution.  Thank you.  =)

Comment: A static variable in a member function does **not** exist for the lifetime of the instance the member function was called on. It exists for the lifetime of the program after this member function was called.

Comment: A non `nullptr` value perhaps??

Comment: Yes, it's called 'design'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could allow `data` to exist in the class, but default its value to `NULL`. When you `delete []` it, it will be a `nop` if it was not allocated.

If you're using C++11, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, as it is safer (because `nullptr` does not convert to integral type, and `NULL` is usually defined as `0`)

Alternatively, create `data` as a `vector<float> data` instead of a `float*`, and you don't need to do anything in the destructor. You're not really wasting any memory if you never add anything to the vector. (Thanks Manu343726 and Malloc)

Comment: And prefer `std::vector` as buffer, instead of manual memory management. Using vector you should not write anything on the dtor at all.

Comment: @Manu343726 and Malloc: That's a good point, I'll amend this answer.

Comment: default to `NULL` or `nullptr`

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: We don't need no fancy C++ 11 here! (Post updated :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Embrace `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Class {
public:
  void func(bool test)
  {
    if (test) {
      data_.resize(1000000);
    }
  }

  ~Class() {
    std::cout << "Destroying data of size: " << data_.size() << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::vector<float> data_;
};

int main() {
  Class A;
  Class B;

  A.func(true);
  B.func(false);
}
```

This prints:

```
Destroying data of size: 0
Destroying data of size: 1000000
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/U1JxPT)

Answer (score 0):

You could also defer all this logic to vector.  When your class is destructed the vector destructor will take care of all cases. In general vector is an acceptable solution to buffers.

```
class Class {
  public:
    void func()
    {
      if (A) {
        // do something
      } else if (B) {
        // need data buffer, which we will recycle
        MyVector.resize(1000000,0.0);
        // do something with the data
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
   private: 
      vector<float> MyVecto_;

  }
}
```